# Celery : schedule a task which use the last execution result

Tags: python, celery

I'm starting with Celery (integrated with Django).

I would like to schedule a task, every 5 minutes. This task can have a parameter which is the last task execution result (it acts as a context).

I found how to chain and schedule tasks but I can't find the right way to provide this "context" to the next task.

Sorry if I missed something in the Celery's documentation..

Thanks for your help,
Arnaud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be better to use some persistent storage for this problem. But you can run delayed tasks in celery using `eta` or `countdown` [parameters](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown):

> The ETA (estimated time of arrival) lets you set a specific date and
>   time that is the earliest time at which your task will be executed.
>   countdown is a shortcut to set eta by seconds into the future.

Comment: Hey Alex, 

Thanks for your answer. For the moment, I'm using a Redis DB to store the results. Do you considerer it as persistent ?

I understand the eta/countdown but I can't see how to retrieve the last result from the next task ? 

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @arnaud.breton My idea was to send result as a parameter to the task. After computations is done, just schedule delayed task with the result of your computations right inside the task. Sure it would be more reliable to use storage (e.g. Redis) and periodic tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the alex vasi's solution.

First, I tried to use the same id for each task but sometimes, the task can't retrieve the last result.

I moved to the callback way, so each time my task is ending, I'm starting an another task with the correct ETA and passing the last result as an argument.
It works pretty well.

For errors handling, I attached a method to the [task_failure signal](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#task-failure).